# ScopeKey doesn't work in nuxt.js auth module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Recently i started to learn how to use Nuxtjs and while learning how to use its Auth module i came across a problem.

I'm able to log in and I want to check the scope of the accounts, i tried doing it using the "scopeKey" property of "Auth". From the back end i get the "scope" from the databse and it can either be "user" or "admin".

I have tried to set the scope with

```
scopeKey: 'scope'
```

But I get that scope is "undefined"/"null" when checking with

```
this.$auth.hasScope('admin') / this.$auth.hasScope('user')
```

or "this.$auth.hasScope(admin)" return an empty value when setting "scopeKey" to

```
scopeKey: 'data.scope'
```

or

```
scopeKey: 'user.scope'
```

Here is my auth strategy:

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        scopeKey: 'scope',
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: 'api/auth/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token',
          },
          logout: {
            url: 'api/auth/logout',
            method: 'get'
          },
          user: {
            url: 'api/me',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: data
          }
        }
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/auth/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/auth/login',
      home: '/dash/'
    }
  }
```

and here it is an example of the json that the auth module reads when i log in:

```
"data": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test1",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "scope": "admin",
        "created_at": "2019-08-01 13:11:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-08-01 13:11:49"
    },
```

I can access the scope value on the front end page with

```
$auth.user.scope
```

or with

```
$auth.$state.user.scope
```

But how can I give the "scope" to the "scopeKey" property in the nuxt.config.js file while setting the "auth" properties/strategy?

edit:

I have tried moving it inside the auth object or deleting the property and I still get false on `$auth.hasScope('admin')` and `$auth.hasScope('user')` which means `scopeKey` is still undefined and i'm not sure why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scopeKey is 'scope' by default. You don't need to set it again.

For me it worked by doing server side change.

When I put string value in scope, it does not work

```
$data['scope'] = "admin";
```

But when I changed it to array, `$auth.hasScope('admin')` works;

```
$data['scope'] = array("admin", "test");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

`scopeKey: 'scope'` should not be placed inside `strategies` object.

Put it directly in the `auth` object.

Take a look at [default config](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/blob/master/lib/module/defaults.js).

P.S. You can even delete this property from your `auth` config object, because `'scope'` is default value for `scopeKey`.

Comment: I have tried moving it inside the `auth` object or deleting the property and i still get false on `$auth.hasScope('admin')` and `$auth.hasScope('user')` which means `scopeKey` is still undefined and i'm not sure why.

Comment: For me it worked by moving it inside the auth object. Thank you very it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `hasScope()` is not working for me too, so I directly checked the user object, I also has token in my response.
I am having a **type** variable in my response that tells me if the user is admin or someone else.

add this into your middleware

```
export default function ({ $auth, redirect }) {

    if (!$auth.loggedIn) {
        return redirect('/')
    }
    if ($auth.user.type != 'Super Admin') {  // Super Admin or whatever the user you want to check
        return redirect('/')
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `user.scope` must be an array for `hasScope` to work, assuming your `scopeKey` is the default called scope.